# Dryer vent and bath vent combined

Tags: venting

A neighbor is working to control moisture in his crawl space. He has a bath vent going to the crawl space. His repair is to connect the bath vent pipe to his dryer vent. The logic is that he would not have another protrusion through the wall allowing potential moisture intrusion. I think this is a bad idea to combine moisture from the bath vent into the dryer vent. What do you think?

Comment: Is the dryer in question electric or gas?

Comment: ...and this is your business *why?* It's generally a dumb idea (bath moisture will come out the dryer, dryer moisture will come out the bath vent, if gas dryer combustion products as well - the vents have no "sense of direction") but very much in *nosy neighbor* territory.

Comment: Or this? [Combine two bathroom exhaust vents?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/194286/combine-two-bathroom-exhaust-vents)

Comment: Or any of [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adiy.stackexchange.com+combining+exhaust+vents)?

Comment: @Ecnerwal perhaps the neighbor asked the OP's opinion on the plan, the OP provided it, and came here for advice to confirm their opinion?